# How can i loop through several columns and join their values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, join

I have few data frame columns.

```
colnames = ['dot0', 'dot1', 'dot2', 'dot3', 'dot4', 'dot5']
```

Their values must be joined with a "." to form a new column named "Connected". I have used map to do it as shown below:

```
df["Connected"] =df['dot0'].map(str) + '.' + df['dot1'].map(str) + '.' + df['dot2'].map(str) + '.' + df['dot3'].map(str) + '.' + df['dot4'].map(str) + '.' + df['dot5'].map(str)
```

But, is there a simpler way where I can join by looping through the values columns.

Something like:

```
for i in colnames:
    df[i].map
```

Comment: `df["Connected"] = df[colnames].astype(str).agg(".",join,axis=1)` ?

Comment: to correct @anky's typo: `.agg(".".join, axis=1)`